# Angular - How to get an element's width and height

Tags: angular

How can I get a tables first td element's width and height?

```
<div class="page">
  <table>
   <tr>
     <td></td>
     ...
   </tr>
</div>
```

Comment: Use `@ViewChild` to get an `ElementRef` of the desired element. On this you can access attributes like `el.nativeElement.offsetWidth` where `el` is the reference to the element.

Comment: table rows and columns are generated by ngFor so I'd rather not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use clientHeight and clientWidth - note that the queryAll selector is only targetting the single td in this demo - you will need to extend that selector to get the correct TD that you are after.

```js
let tableCell = document.querySelector('td');

let cellWidth = tableCell.clientWidth +'px';
let cellHeight = tableCell.clientHeight +'px';


console.log('width: ' + cellWidth, ' / height: ' + cellHeight);
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <table>
   <tr>
     <td>Test</td>
   </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```